# Copying all .dll files from one virtual server to another with Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, virtual-machine, code-cleanup

I'm trying to copy all the .dll files from C:\windows in a virtual server to a new virtual server. I've managed to get all the .dll files, however I can't find a way to copy them to the new virtual server and was wondering if anyone might know how to do this with Powershell.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') 
$server = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the server name with files you want to copy", "Server")
$server2 = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the server name you want files copied to", "Server")
$destinationName = ("\\" + $server2 + '\C$\windows')
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path ("\\" + $server + '\C$\windows') -recurse | Where {$_.extension -eq ".dll"}
```

What would I have to do with my $Files variable to copy it to a new VM? I know of the copy-item cmdlet, but unaware of how to use it to move all of this to a new virtual server.

EDIT:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') 
$server = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the server name with files you want to copy", "Server")
$server2 = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the server name you want files copied to", "Server")
$destinationName = ("\\" + $server2 + '\C$\windows')

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path ("\\" + $server + '\C$\windows') -recurse | Where {$_.extension -eq ".dll"}
foreach($dll in $Files){
$destinationName +=  
cp $dll.fullname $destinationName}
```

I want to get string of path to be "\$server2\C$\windows\ ..\ .. " for each specific file.

At the moment if the code runs it'll make every file/directory appear as "\$server2\C$\windows" and not get the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really nearly there, actually.

`$Files = Get-ChildItem...` makes `$Files` become an array of items, and because Powershell was designed to work with objects, you just would use `$Files` as an argument to `Copy-Item`. The caveat with this is that, for whatever reason, `Copy-Item` doesn't use the full path property from the objects obtained with `Get-ChildItem` (instead it just gets the filenames, so you'd have to be in that directory for it to work), so the easiest way would be this:

`foreach($dll in $Files){cp $dll.fullname $destinationName}`

**To copy while preserving directory structure**, you want to take the starting full path and just modify it to reflect the new root directory/server. This can be done in one line similar to the above, but for clarity and readability, I'm expanding it into the following multi-line setup:

```
foreach($dll in $Files){
    $target = $dll.fullname -replace "\\\\$server","\\$server2"
    $targetDir = $($dll.directory.fullname -replace "\\\\$server","\\$server2")
    if(!(Test-Path $targetDir){
        mkdir $targetDir
    }
    cp $dll.fullname $target
}
```

To explain, the `$target...` line takes the full path of the current `$dll`, say `\\SourceServer\C$\windows\some\rather\deep\file.dll`, and regex replaces the part of the path that says `\\SourceServer` and replaces it with `\\DestinationServer` so that the rest of the path is left intact. That is, it will now be `\\TargetServer\C$\windows\some\rather\deep\file.dll`. This method eliminates the need for your `$destinationName` variable.
The `Test-Path` bit makes sure that the the parent folder of the file exists remotely before copying, otherwise it will fail out.

Comment: Thanks! There's one thing however that I noticed with my string, when I test this at the moment all it is doing is copying everything directly to C:\Windows on the new VM. I notice that this is because I'm assigning $server2 to be a static string, however I want to append to this string and append for each file location.

Comment: I've edited my code to show better what I mean. I'm slightly confused on how to explain this personally, so I figure showing the code will make more sense as well.

Comment: Thanks SpellingD, this is closer to what I'm trying to get. I tested this and it works for the most part, however I'm not getting any directories inside of the specified path right now. Is there a way to recurse and get all of the directories inside of Windows using this method?

Comment: You are filtering to only look for .dll files, so it won't find any directories to copy. The update I've added creates the directories required on the target machine, before it just assumed the directories already existed. If you're still having issues, you may want to consider looking into the `Robocopy` built-in utility -- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx